# Openlayers not displaying WFS layer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, display

First, I realize there are a number of very similar posts on this site and others, but none have resolved the issue I'm having.

I have a layer I'm trying to serve via WFS in Geoserver/OpenLayers that simply will not display.  The layer displays fine if served through WMS, but not WFS.  I can also see that the layer is returned properly from the GET request, but again, will not display on screen.

At first, I did have the cross-domain issue, but added the proxy script as a resolution.  At that point, I could see the data was being returned accordingly in the XML, however, still wouldn’t display in the screen.

My first guess was a projection issue, but no matter what resolution I tried (many), nothing would display the data.  Reading the coordinates in the returned XML also indicated that the data should display correctly. Initially, the layer I was working with had a native/declared projection of EPSG:2232 (CO State Plane Central US Ft, NAD83).  After many attempts, I finally just tried re-projecting the data to EPSG:900913, as that is what the map frame is projected to, thinking it should remove any issues regarding projection.  Still didn’t show anything.  I then added a simple point directly in the middle of the map frame which should also occur within the geometry of the layer I’m trying to load.  To my surprise, the point loaded and is displayed on screen, but the other WFS layer is not.

At this point, not sure what to think, but pretty frustrated. If anyone has any insight on this, please let me know.  Code is below; returned XML showing layer loaded is below code.  Thanks in advance...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="EN">
<head>
  <script src='http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/adapte/ext/extbase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"></link>

<script src="GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.1/proj4-src.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.1/proj4.js'></script>
<script src='js/proj4js-combined.js'></script>

<style>
    html,body {
        height: 99%;
        width: 99%;
    }
    #gxmap {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }   
    .header_class{
        background-color: #0d66a5;
    }
    /* Override standard CSS styles for panels */
    .x-panel-header {
      background: url(css/custom_panel_header.png) center left repeat-x;
      background-color:#639;
      text-align: left;
      border-color: #000;
    }

    .x-panel-body {
      border-color: #000;
      background-color: #abbcc8;
    }

    .x-panel-header-text {
      font: bold 14px Consolas, Arial, san-serif;
      color: #eee;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5;
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var lon = -106.353;
    var lat = 39.601;
    var zoom = 14;

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        numZoomLevels: 18,
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(),
            ]
    });


// use proxy if requesting features cross-domain
OpenLayers.ProxyHost= "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

    //Add Google base layers
    var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Satellite",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
    );
    var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Physical",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, numZoomLevels: 22}
    );

    //Add WMS layers from GeoServer
    var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('sup', {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    reportError: true,
    visibility: true,           
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                       url:  "http://xxxxxxxx.com/geoserver/Vail/wfs",
                       featureType: "vail_sup_geo_merc",
                       featureNS: "http://xxxxxxxx.com/Vail",
                       version: "1.1.0",
                       //srsName: "EPSG:900913",
                       srsName: "urn:ogc:def:crs:epsg::900913",
            })
});

var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4808100, -11839246));
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

var vectorLayer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay2");
    var feature2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-11839246, 4808100));
    vectorLayer2.addFeatures(feature2);


    //Add all layers to the OpenLayers mapframe     
    map.addLayers([
        gsat, gphy, wfs, vectorLayer2
    ]);

    //Variables to define transformation to use when centering mapframe below
    var fromProj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var toProj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

    //Center the OpenLayers mapframe
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(fromProj,toProj));



////CREATES THE COLLAPSIBLE LAYER LIST ON SIDE      

// create our own layer node UI class, using the TreeNodeUIEventMixin
var LayerNodeUI = Ext.extend(GeoExt.tree.LayerNodeUI, new GeoExt.tree.TreeNodeUIEventMixin());

// using OpenLayers.Format.JSON to create a nice formatted string of the
// configuration for editing it in the UI
var treeConfig = [{
    nodeType: "gx_overlaylayercontainer",
    expanded: true,
    text: 'KML Overlays',
    // render the nodes inside this container with a radio button,
    // and assign them the group "foo".
    loader: {
        baseAttrs: {
            radioGroup: "foo",
            uiProvider: "layernodeui"
        }, 
        //createNode: createIconNode
    }
},
{
    nodeType: "gx_baselayercontainer",
    expanded: true,
    text: 'Base Layers',
}/*, 
}*/];
// The line below is only needed for this example, because we want to allow
// interactive modifications of the tree configuration using the
// "Show/Edit Tree Config" button. Don't use this line in your code.
//treeConfig = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON().write(treeConfig, true);

// create the tree with the configuration from above
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    //renderTo: 'layerlist',
    border: true,
    region: "west",
    title: "Layers",
    width: 200,
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapseMode: "mini",
    autoScroll: true,
    plugins: [
        new GeoExt.plugins.TreeNodeRadioButton({
            listeners: {
                "radiochange": function(node) {
                    alert(node.text + " is now the active layer.");
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        // applyLoader has to be set to false to not interfer with loaders
        // of nodes further down the tree hierarchy
        applyLoader: false,
        uiProviders: {
            "layernodeui": LayerNodeUI
        }
    }),
    root: {
        nodeType: "async",
        // the children property of an Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode is used to
        // provide an initial set of layer nodes. We use the treeConfig
        // from above, that we created with OpenLayers.Format.JSON.write.
        //children: Ext.decode(treeConfig)
        // Don't use the line above in your application. Instead, use
        children: treeConfig

    },
    listeners: {
        "radiochange": function(node){
            alert(node.layer.name + " is now the the active layer.");
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: false,
});

////END COLLAPSIBLE LAYER LIST      

    //Create the GeoExt MapPanel and write to div
    var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        xtype : 'gx_mappanel',
        //renderTo: 'gxmap',
        //height: 600,
        id : 'mapCenter',
        region: "center",
        layout: "fit",
        hideBorders: false,
        //deferredRender: true,
        map: map,
        zoom: zoom
    });


    var headerPanel = new Ext.Panel ({
        title: "",
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 150,
        region: "north",
        baseCls: 'header_class',
        html: '<div style="position: relative; float: left;"><img src="imgs/elev8_logo.png" width="181px" height="150px"</img></div><div><p>Hello World!</p></div>',
    });

    //Sets all custom legend image items
    var layerRec2 = mapPanel.layers.getAt(2);
    var layerRec3 = mapPanel.layers.getAt(3);
    var layerRec4 = mapPanel.layers.getAt(4);

    legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
        xtype: "gx_legendpanel",
        title: 'Legend',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
        layerStore: mapPanel.layers,
        autoScroll: true,
        defaults: {
            style: 'padding:5px',
            baseParams: {
                FORMAT: 'image/png',
                LEGEND_OPTIONS: 'forceLabels:on'
            }
        }
    }); 

    var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel ({
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        activeTab: 0,
        region: "west",
        width: 200,
        split: true,
        layoutOnTabChange : true,
        items:[
        tree, legendPanel
    ]
    });

    new Ext.Viewport({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: "border",
        items: [headerPanel, tabPanel, mapPanel]
    });
});
```

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"xmlns:wfs="http//www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:Vail="www.elev8-ims.com/Vail" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="1" timeStamp="2014-07-17T01:50:17.109Z" xsi:schemaLocation="www.elev8-ims.com/Vail http://elev8-ims.com:80/geoserver/Vail/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=Vail%3Avail_sup_geo_merc http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://elev8-ims.com:80/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<gml:featureMembers>
<Vail:vail_sup_geo_merc gml:id="vail_sup_geo_merc.1">
<Vail:objectid>1</Vail:objectid>
<Vail:mgt_area1>8.25</Vail:mgt_area1>
<Vail:acres>12226.2353516</Vail:acres>
<Vail:shape_leng>39766.6763806</Vail:shape_leng>
<Vail:shape_area>49477790.8367</Vail:shape_area>
<Vail:geom>
<gml:MultiSurface srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#900913">
<gml:surfaceMember>
<gml:Polygon srsDimension="2">
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing srsDimension="2">
<gml:posList>-1.1839842372410642E7 4813211.241289002 -1.1839799954200424E7 4813094.675643468 -1.183873839697669E7 4812492.12925204 -1.1837874124400748E7 4812001.152670531 -1.1837219048842695E7 4811632.009653842 -1.1837100668273155E7 4811565.426771214 -1.1837117602245849E7 4811520.900905828 -1.1837179034100479E7 4811317.493255342 -1.183726723188812E7 4811142.333669212 -1.1837337404433101E7 4810935.557711602 -1.1837416145971376E7 4810713.683312595 -1.183746107078593E7 4810584.100840738 -1.1837483484798623E7 4810516.076148242 -1.183745587759037E7 4810431.19607419 -1.1837333164948856E7 4810253.347008991 -1.1837255348633142E7 4810139.943694676 -1.1837149825256033E7 4809938.402338129 -1.183704721121349E7 4809731.618437712 -1.1836977733432569E7 4809588.149499887 -1.1836908632326327E7 4809468.74727273 -1.1836866074385885E7 4809363.922939378 -1.1836808145931456E7 4809208.577254133 -1.1836706650615148E7 4809077.932253958 -1.1836611592484947E7 4808988.229593278 -1.1836499785294889E7 4808951.482820602 -1.183637049020686E7 4808921.501235856 -1.1836241664894354E7 4808923.411802221 -1.1836092512310473E7 4808934.086403418 -1.1835961287741104E7 4808974.436600136 -1.1835873584552504E7 4808984.198576877 -1.1835816272417806E7 4808968.769135994 -1.1835736379009513E7 4808912.674153336 -1.1835684277462356E7 4808854.863242968 -1.1835625956031641E7 4808770.445431487 -1.1835514731128203E7 4808673.795118875 -1.1835409309469158E7 4808575.120386129 -1.1835269566949418E7 4808427.4705646355 -1.1835196524519935E7 4808354.344956346 -1.183470105780954E7 4808233.396288321 -1.1834594153767355E7 4808229.109951361 -1.183348272671523E7 4808181.560523641 -1.1833292070230015E7 4808084.088227495 -1.1833259450666789E7 4808067.653306251 -1.1833064670749435E7 4807871.953631184 -1.1832989122472102E7 4807746.803185409 -1.1832967871659752E7 4807711.298965648 -1.1832873863217704E7 4807529.130048374 -1.183277063822485E7 4807343.834376196 -1.1832656565842772E7 4807036.356615276 -1.1832565291073801E7 4806749.378695154 -1.1832619516295757E7 4806716.0485681845 -1.1832713854556274E7 4806675.651875635 -1.1832805756903367E7 4806660.006344069 -1.1832911674546298E7 4806647.400085453 -1.183301210609993E7 4806640.091896156 -1.1833126289823921E7 4806621.510648703 -1.1833218116727285E7 4806598.052234937 -1.1833362746033069E7 4806559.5103753535 -1.1833426727612438E7 4806544.264961978 -1.183349595117944E7 4806504.207439266 -1.1833570529154878E7 4806447.165689716 -1.1833625397464149E7 4806381.948090026 -1.1833677532231973E7 4806316.751227991 -1.1833724029553145E7 4806251.655822132 -1.183371615570394E7 4806094.286236267 -1.1833706900346216E7 4805161.30932552 -1.1833697992581503E7 4804544.630894695 -1.1833693787460916E7 4804158.218068742 -1.183368966552093E7 4803864.863871072 -1.1834939801174436E7 4803091.279279201 -1.183624384914216E7 4802746.785641322 -1.1836271373821154E7 4802650.101461854 -1.1836370020424698E7 4802473.640992311 -1.1836547148929743E7 4802279.119229985 -1.1836758864741271E7 4802140.016774218 -1.1836897554728992E7 4802008.519873556 -1.183716035608012E7 4801902.487681799 -1.1837373027991174E7 4801831.665625574 -1.1837546302653583E7 4801755.578122755 -1.1837759702271402E7 4801735.47046217 -1.1837951084221814E7 4801744.324684961 -1.183813021945036E7 4801685.037905728 -1.1838338417699426E7 4801692.980290782 -1.1838529624313168E7 4801690.106736234 -1.1838643218254345E7 4801761.897627306 -1.1838690393111488E7 4801908.1886885 -1.1838700137790684E7 4802037.475330823 -1.183873114093756E7 4802238.009405402 -1.1839218330664873E7 4803138.790793877 -1.1839699469003707E7 4803398.86844631 -1.1839923960637776E7 4803688.229055243 -1.1840631437659584E7 4804713.232156909 -1.1840833121459844E7 4805075.176397916 -1.1840850857025027E7 4805106.774835675 -1.1840863516301526E7 4805130.008646315 -1.1840876223068414E7 4805152.58941042 -1.1840888872574903E7 4805175.171083354 -1.1840901522139024E7 4805197.75278931 -1.1840914190866964E7 4805220.334236244 -1.184092685043707E7 4805243.568220452 -1.184093950017502E7 4805266.150026862 -1.1840941288012631E7 4805269.365332419 -1.184095216907692E7 4805288.731574173 -1.1840964818639211E7 4805311.294263758 -1.1840977468550092E7 4805333.876169163 -1.184099017583792E7 4805356.457230995 -1.1841002835760137E7 4805379.691423169 -1.184101548584494E7 4805402.273428976 -1.1841028155093951E7 4805424.855175519 -1.1841040805294083E7 4805447.437247342 -1.1841053455551855E7 4805470.019352175 -1.1841066134874277E7 4805493.253425645 -1.1841078785248252E7 4805515.835597922 -1.1841091435388643E7 4805538.398619947 -1.1841104104984703E7 4805560.980565784 -1.1841116793745346E7 4805583.562252139 -1.184112945425471E7 4805606.796791492 -1.1841142124024838E7 4805629.378837655 -1.184115477474571E7 4805651.961209317 -1.1841167425524231E7 4805674.543614001 -1.1841180095467472E7 4805697.125759124 -1.1841192756270418E7 4805720.3604721 -1.1841205407222806E7 4805742.94297724 -1.184121807734004E7 4805765.525222729 -1.1841230766330726E7 4805788.088024783 -1.184124343656345E7 4805810.670336152 -1.1841256097660055E7 4805833.9052226525 -1.184126874890172E7 4805856.48789417 -1.184128141930845E7 4805879.070305914 -1.184128504384982E7 4805886.172025435 -1.1841297083785387E7 4805908.764144192 -1.1841309152800577E7 4805932.008260362 -1.1841321260087596E7 4805955.251828269 -1.184133331010873E7 4805978.496312249 -1.1841345369082715E7 4806001.069096689 -1.1841357419216312E7 4806024.313654201 -1.1841369488514274E7 4806047.557956259 -1.1841381528839007E7 4806070.150324411 -1.1841393598249542E7 4806093.3946999945 -1.184140564860896E7 4806116.639406102 -1.1841417708208205E7 4806139.231587931 -1.1841429815711988E7 4806162.456303901 -1.1841441866240649E7 4806185.701120992 -1.1841453926006744E7 4806208.293409365 -1.1841465976647904E7 4806231.538300021 -1.1841478046453813E7 4806254.782935015 -1.184149008727856E7 4806277.375623252 -1.1841502157197054E7 4806300.620331769 -1.1841514208064046E7 4806323.865371034 -1.1841526267871583E7 4806346.438687958 -1.184153837617602E7 4806369.682920791 -1.1841550427212272E7 4806392.928071037 -1.1841568379141E7 4806427.135747704 -1.1841654769398533E7 4806444.691359865 -1.184185505742858E7 4806496.283283057 -1.1842055694283286E7 4806569.32006916 -1.184216662503359E7 4806622.934736971 -1.1842329362231936E7 4806693.307916989 -1.184253975607988E7 4806727.805784436 -1.184274641370588E7 4806745.431546156 -1.1842867119807947E7 4806764.38434233 -1.184298068885379E7 4806769.130538866 -1.184309094755945E7 4806781.084660566 -1.1843218323872752E7 4806786.285684687 -1.1843334720252307E7 4806749.974895791 -1.1843420370327324E7 4806727.823146658 -1.184358881007427E7 4806718.698774113 -1.1843698444935307E7 4806689.013729627 -1.184373893776269E7 4806640.216825064 -1.1843795559236946E7 4806518.286640758 -1.184386321410566E7 4806445.003386068 -1.1843955379086062E7 4806401.925775107 -1.1844058149512744E7 4806372.344768248 -1.1844288555362247E7 4806368.747018631 -1.1844453418361101E7 4806352.5067113275 -1.1844629042632954E7 4806363.4206135105 -1.184480099620539E7 4806360.726240807 -1.1844921469259448E7 4806365.99433971 -1.1845045381859055E7 4806371.20697501 -1.1845131581043513E7 4806383.515816764 -1.184520061487562E7 4806399.355925027 -1.1845349397416435E7 4806456.234556061 -1.1845415843205588E7 4806524.155857136 -1.1845493128243774E7 4806626.4095300315 -1.1845553756144749E7 4806763.429578827 -1.184561388817385E7 4806869.850536348 -1.1845664902144738E7 4807051.9112333935 -1.1845718086656353E7 4807372.576469413 -1.1845757597903276E7 4807699.973288885 -1.1845766065090299E7 4807800.05951255 -1.1845778017223652E7 4807906.617053899 -1.1845766221750312E7 4808031.111441255 -1.1845753979238778E7 4808128.284155766 -1.1845727506448247E7 4808194.436539404 -1.1845680191843243E7 4808250.515493184 -1.184562595438934E7 4808302.788327109 -1.1845562076262496E7 4808397.514520183 -1.1845491418246811E7 4808498.854514239 -1.1845437829246148E7 4808592.786298471 -1.1845383793126103E7 4808659.374830771 -1.184534300226279E7 4808757.655055286 -1.1845313261382386E7 4808766.587516971 -1.1845292582037514E7 4808777.9685028745 -1.1845274673504265E7 4808799.075532558 -1.1845254225401698E7 4808822.832887906 -1.1845233679147748E7 4808843.981426929 -1.184521577067306E7 4808865.107683201 -1.1845213230857247E7 4808867.738807867 -1.1845182471143302E7 4808902.080680983 -1.1845164510047559E7 4808918.620411496 -1.1845154136681424E7 4808924.00426533 -1.1845143841924775E7 4808931.978078258 -1.1845128491479518E7 4808950.434559768 -1.1845108083409496E7 4808976.801754277 -1.184508757721344E7 4809000.560103149 -1.1845069627178738E7 4809019.057466642 -1.1845059513764309E7 4809037.45091716 -1.184504947211164E7 4809061.67834233 -1.1845039422985626E7 4809087.882955375 -1.1845021351014584E7 4809098.570179481 -1.1845000780029334E7 4809114.517514855 -1.1844980151638389E7 4809130.465734737 -1.184495962117004E7 4809149.022853084 -1.1844949409439882E7 4809164.807516296 -1.1844944604480226E7 4809188.952930485 -1.1844934390570227E7 4809202.1464024745 -1.184492681640968E7 4809217.889721896 -1.1844911627381608E7 4809246.766577418 -1.1844898856367214E7 4809265.1827998785 -1.1844891201139787E7 4809275.72568448 -1.1844873209926145E7 4809291.632553586 -1.18448631362105E7 4809312.616982405 -1.1844832159809241E7 4809331.971506411 -1.1844806391488375E7 4809350.610852169 -1.1844788359399257E7 4809363.907819369 -1.1844765230694886E7 4809385.097039351 -1.18447471581914E7 4809395.803289105 -1.1844729125941591E7 4809409.100212111 -1.1844700778908843E7 4809430.37118813 -1.1844682665674154E7 4809438.467479417 -1.1844669904439712E7 4809457.55543717 -1.1844649534416497E7 4809486.513778957 -1.1844634485881114E7 4809524.506514195 -1.184461673659688E7 4809556.034477854 -1.184460175851972E7 4809598.575623602 -1.1844576272065159E7 4809635.426911669 -1.1844553546876125E7 4809682.658193863 -1.1844530457189204E7 4809706.438336025 -1.1844515045088096E7 4809722.304860065 -1.1844478887007663E7 4809741.759405624 -1.1844437602226166E7 4809768.43488265 -1.1844372934449866E7 4809800.044648004 -1.1844332042450909E7 4809839.747660017 -1.1844271218634427E7 4809909.68872997 -1.1844200375841819E7 4810000.633459161 -1.1844142994491745E7 4810074.456315386 -1.184404476524354E7 4810176.233667118 -1.1843977036995132E7 4810246.302272774 -1.1843936553263364E7 4810299.01442387 -1.1843881277537078E7 4810357.159709361 -1.184390328584548E7 4810692.094422255 -1.1843942991411522E7 4811295.636843553 -1.184398193869509E7 4811888.167876226 -1.1844377728183193E7 4811876.779362358 -1.1844391006308015E7 4812502.942580688 -1.1844385339411214E7 4812926.285190933 -1.1844375390064972E7 4813668.8053751215 -1.1843858050705494E7 4813686.010652031 -1.1842532679885067E7 4813713.107755968 -1.1841676994156756E7 4813722.388093668 -1.184142501936277E7 4813726.260445469 -1.1841428908405418E7 4813215.656908593 -1.1840144589004926E7 4813211.848279349 -1.1839842372410642E7 4813211.241289002</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:exterior>
<gml:interior>
<gml:LinearRing srsDimension="2">
<gml:posList>-1.1843859786097806E7 4808097.456351724 -1.1843870878411936E7 4809233.756151737 -1.1844407770350385E7 4809238.38501398 -1.18444043238412E7 4808681.251704357 -1.1844954164404744E7 4808686.953667619 -1.1844946749407073E7 4808127.32242108 -1.1843859786097806E7 4808097.456351724</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:interior>
<gml:interior>
<gml:LinearRing srsDimension="2">
<gml:posList>-1.1843349536793811E7 4809060.904634446 -1.1843349873365182E7 4808998.402745624 -1.1842304869535616E7 4809004.182020489 -1.1842310181655383E7 4809520.9381895065 -1.1843350199827883E7 4809524.352886233 -1.1843349536793811E7 4809060.904634446</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:interior>
<gml:interior>
<gml:LinearRing srsDimension="2">
<gml:posList>-1.1837756947164824E7 4808309.172529527 -1.1837748853249881E7 4808309.94629531 -1.1837741027175676E7 4808312.021169416 -1.1837733707692623E7 4808316.02694847 -1.1837727143558789E7 4808320.693170955 -1.1837721477680173E7 4808326.631877305 -1.1837716910887195E7 4808333.206693605 -1.1837713576967606E7 4808340.415619711 -1.1837711590597631E7 4808348.2569414405 -1.1837711028229583E7 4808356.729516503 -1.183771183226332E7 4808364.529076744 -1.183771406030585E7 4808372.959891009 -1.1837717606841907E7 4808380.065838123 -1.1837722366888415E7 4808386.501053139 -1.1837728206659611E7 4808392.267536101 -1.1837734906228157E7 4808396.71600875 -1.1837742341781866E7 4808400.520083139 -1.1837750226076532E7 4808402.35972793 -1.1837758339165723E7 4808402.871610131 -1.1837766433439601E7 4808402.117016825 -1.1837774259577924E7 4808400.042102863 -1.1837781578819541E7 4808396.01707087 -1.183778816237334E7 4808391.369679902 -1.183779382824739E7 4808385.430897717 -1.1837798375899835E7 4808378.856299107 -1.183780170977009E7 4808371.647318302 -1.1837803715185918E7 4808363.805675639 -1.1837804315700645E7 4808355.332518522 -1.1837803473371437E7 4808347.533546996 -1.1837801226148047E7 4808339.10306171 -1.1837797679568568E7 4808331.997174102 -1.183779293861349E7 4808325.561743942 -1.183778709884557E7 4808319.795336885 -1.1837780379909331E7 4808315.328030008 -1.1837772944690704E7 4808311.543203706 -1.1837765060463937E7 4808309.703591929 -1.1837756947164824E7 4808309.172529527</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:interior>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:surfaceMember>
</gml:MultiSurface>
</Vail:geom>
</Vail:vail_sup_geo_merc>
</gml:featureMembers>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Comment: 900913 is not the correct EPSG code. 3857 is the correct code. What happens when you try that?

Comment: Well, they are basically identical (I believe?).  Plugged it in anyways and get precisely the same results.  Thnx for weighing in anyways... not sure where to go at the moment....

Comment: Did you, by any change, ever solve this problem? I am having exactly the same issue.